# Нужно выполнить действие если в текстовике "numbers.txt" число больше 5000

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import time
import mouse
import keyboard
import pyperclip

file1 = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('link.txt', 'r')

while True:
    # считываем строку
    line1 = file1.readline()
    if not line1:
        break

    print(line1)
    mouse.move(199, 46)
    mouse.click('left')
    pyperclip.copy(line1.strip())
    keyboard.send('ctrl+a')
    keyboard.send('ctrl+v')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # считываем строку
    line2 = file2.readline()
    if not line2:
        break

    print(line2)
    pyperclip.copy(line2.strip())
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mouse.move(66, 183)
    mouse.click('left')
    time.sleep(0.5)

# закрываем файл
file1.close
file2.close
```

Хочу сделать что бы во время этого цикла выполнялось действие "mouse.drag(1852, 509, 2742, 505, duration=0.2)" если число введенное строкой `print(line1)` было больше чем 5000

Answer (score 0):

Просто используйте `if`:

```
if int(line1) > 5000:
    mouse.drag(1852, 509, 2742, 505, duration=0.2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я видимо не правильно использовал "if" по этому не получалось то что планировал